# DomCrawler does not bring all the links?

Tags: php, symfony, parsing, dom, domcrawler

not all links on the target site gives only why 5 links?

div.td.cm4.takimlar the structures are the same

```
<?php 
require("library/vendor/autoload.php");

use Goutte\Client;
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$client = new Client(HttpClient::create(['timeout' => 60]));
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-bulteni');

$nodeValues = $crawler->filter('div.td.cm4.takimlar')->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
return $node->filter('a')->attr('href');
});

var_dump($nodeValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got 376 items in `var_dump()`  with following code

```
$nodeValues = $crawler->filter('div.td.cm4.takimlar > a')->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) {

    // return $node;
    return $node->attr('href');
});

var_dump($nodeValues);
```

some items

```
array (size=376)
  0 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/kaiserslautern-zwickau-iddaa-oranlari-105726' (length=91)
  1 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/wurzburger-kickers-eintracht-braunschweig-iddaa-oranlari-105740' (length=110)
  2 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/uerdingen-preussen-munster-iddaa-oranlari-105737' (length=95)
  3 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/hansa-rostock-ingolstadt-iddaa-oranlari-105724' (length=93)
  4 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/carl-zeiss-jena-meppen-iddaa-oranlari-105722' (length=91)
  5 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/msv-duisburg-waldhof-mannheim-iddaa-oranlari-105723' (length=98)
  6 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/red-star-laval-iddaa-oranlari-105731' (length=83)
  7 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/lubeck-holstein-kiel-ii-iddaa-oranlari-105729' (length=92)
  8 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/schalke-04-ii-borussia-m-gladbach-ii-iddaa-oranlari-105734' (length=105)
  9 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/sv-lippstadt-08-bergisch-gladbach-iddaa-oranlari-105728' (length=102)
  10 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/homberg-borussia-dortmund-ii-iddaa-oranlari-105738' (length=97)
  11 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/verl-fortuna-dusseldorf-ii-iddaa-oranlari-105733' (length=95)
  12 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/bonner-sc-fortuna-koln-iddaa-oranlari-105721' (length=91)
  13 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/koln-ii-tus-haltern-iddaa-oranlari-105727' (length=88)
  14 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/fsv-frankfurt-saarbrucken-iddaa-oranlari-105905' (length=94)
  15 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/pirmasens-ulm-iddaa-oranlari-105909' (length=82)
  16 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/elversberg-aalen-iddaa-oranlari-105904' (length=85)
  17 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/tsv-steinbach-fc-giessen-iddaa-oranlari-105910' (length=93)
  18 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/kickers-offenbach-bahlinger-sc-iddaa-oranlari-105908' (length=99)
  19 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/homburg-freiburg-ii-iddaa-oranlari-105906' (length=88)
  20 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/al-taawon-al-raed-iddaa-oranlari-105720' (length=86)
  21 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/fc-zlate-moravce-skf-sered-iddaa-oranlari-105739' (length=95)
  22 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/pohronie-msk-zilina-iddaa-oranlari-105730' (length=88)
  23 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/ruzomberok-dac-iddaa-oranlari-105732' (length=83)
  24 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/zemplin-michalovce-nitra-iddaa-oranlari-105741' (length=93)
  25 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/slovan-bratislava-fk-as-trencin-iddaa-oranlari-105735' (length=100)
  26 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/triglav-rudar-iddaa-oranlari-105915' (length=82)
  27 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/kesl%C9%99-zira-iddaa-oranlari-105943' (length=84)
  28 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/institute-coleraine-iddaa-oranlari-105725' (length=88)
  29 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/havelse-altona-93-iddaa-oranlari-105736' (length=86)
  30 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/mbombela-united-real-kings-iddaa-oranlari-105907' (length=95)
  31 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/highlands-park-kaizer-chiefs-iddaa-oranlari-106025' (length=97)
  32 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/happy-wanderers-ts-sporting-iddaa-oranlari-105953' (length=96)
  33 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/club-africain-chebba-iddaa-oranlari-105945' (length=89)
  34 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/us-ben-guerdane-tataouine-iddaa-oranlari-105950' (length=94)
  35 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/etoile-sahel-metlaoui-iddaa-oranlari-105949' (length=90)
  36 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/akhisarspor-karagumruk-iddaa-oranlari-105742' (length=91)
  37 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/slavia-prag-opava-iddaa-oranlari-105746' (length=86)
  38 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/mlada-boleslav-slovacko-iddaa-oranlari-105744' (length=92)
  39 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/slovan-liberec-bohemians-1905-iddaa-oranlari-105747' (length=98)
  40 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/oskarshamns-aik-orebro-iddaa-oranlari-105745' (length=91)
  41 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/elfsborg-brage-iddaa-oranlari-105743' (length=83)
  42 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/al-ain-al-wasl-iddaa-oranlari-105933' (length=83)
  43 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/umm-salal-al-sadd-iddaa-oranlari-105911' (length=86)
  44 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/arka-gdynia-rakow-czestochowa-iddaa-oranlari-105749' (length=98)
  45 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/goztepe-gaziantep-fk-iddaa-oranlari-105467' (length=89)
  46 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/cittadella-juve-stabia-iddaa-oranlari-105752' (length=91)
  47 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/trapani-spezia-iddaa-oranlari-105757' (length=83)
  48 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/virtus-entella-benevento-iddaa-oranlari-105759' (length=93)
  49 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/ascoli-cremonese-iddaa-oranlari-105750' (length=85)
  50 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/lens-caen-iddaa-oranlari-105756' (length=78)
  51 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/hajduk-split-gorica-iddaa-oranlari-105754' (length=88)
  52 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/bologna-udinese-iddaa-oranlari-105466' (length=84)
  53 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/carrarese-gozzano-iddaa-oranlari-105751' (length=86)
  54 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/renate-pizzighettone-iddaa-oranlari-105748' (length=89)
  55 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/virtus-verona-rimini-iddaa-oranlari-105758' (length=89)
  56 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/modena-sudtirol-iddaa-oranlari-105755' (length=84)
  57 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/fc-rieti-teramo-iddaa-oranlari-105753' (length=84)
  58 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/biskra-belouizdad-iddaa-oranlari-105935' (length=86)
  59 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/nc-magra-es-setif-iddaa-oranlari-105934' (length=86)
  60 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/m-gladbach-hoffenheim-iddaa-oranlari-105470' (length=90)
  61 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/hertha-berlin-koln-iddaa-oranlari-105469' (length=87)
  62 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/werder-bremen-dortmund-iddaa-oranlari-105471' (length=91)
  63 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/freiburg-fortuna-dusseldorf-iddaa-oranlari-105468' (length=96)
  64 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/barry-town-caernarfon-town-iddaa-oranlari-105760' (length=95)
  65 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/newtown-bala-town-iddaa-oranlari-105763' (length=86)
  66 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/carmarthen-town-cefn-druids-iddaa-oranlari-105761' (length=96)
  67 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/uwic-cardiff-airbus-uk-iddaa-oranlari-105779' (length=91)
  68 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/fleetwood-town-portsmouth-iddaa-oranlari-105803' (length=94)
  69 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/southend-united-burton-albion-iddaa-oranlari-105841' (length=98)
  70 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/rochdale-coventry-city-iddaa-oranlari-105837' (length=91)
  71 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/milton-keynes-dons-bolton-iddaa-oranlari-105825' (length=94)
  72 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/lincoln-city-gillingham-iddaa-oranlari-105822' (length=92)
  73 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/accrington-stanley-rotherham-united-iddaa-oranlari-105765' (length=104)
  74 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/shrewsbury-town-doncaster-rovers-iddaa-oranlari-105840' (length=101)
  75 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/wycombe-wanderers-tranmere-rovers-iddaa-oranlari-105857' (length=102)
  76 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/afc-wimbledon-blackpool-iddaa-oranlari-105855' (length=92)
  77 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/ipswich-town-oxford-united-iddaa-oranlari-105816' (length=95)
  78 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/sunderland-bristol-rovers-iddaa-oranlari-105846' (length=94)
  79 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/southampton-aston-villa-iddaa-oranlari-105476' (length=92)
  80 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/burnley-afc-bournemouth-iddaa-oranlari-105473' (length=92)
  81 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/crystal-palace-newcastle-utd-iddaa-oranlari-105474' (length=97)
  82 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/sheffield-united-brighton-hove-albion-iddaa-oranlari-105475' (length=106)
  83 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/barcelona-eibar-iddaa-oranlari-105472' (length=84)
  84 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/almeria-fuenlabrada-iddaa-oranlari-105767' (length=88)
  85 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/ad-alcorcon-las-palmas-iddaa-oranlari-105766' (length=91)
  86 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/barnsley-middlesbrough-iddaa-oranlari-105771' (length=91)
  87 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/not-forest-queens-park-rangers-iddaa-oranlari-105828' (length=99)
  88 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/birmingham-city-sheffield-wednesday-iddaa-oranlari-105773' (length=104)
  89 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/swansea-city-huddersfield-town-iddaa-oranlari-105847' (length=99)
  90 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/stoke-city-cardiff-city-iddaa-oranlari-105845' (length=92)
  91 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/preston-north-end-hull-city-iddaa-oranlari-105834' (length=96)
  92 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/wigan-athletic-millwall-iddaa-oranlari-105854' (length=92)
  93 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/charlton-athletic-luton-town-iddaa-oranlari-105782' (length=97)
  94 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/leeds-united-reading-iddaa-oranlari-105820' (length=89)
  95 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/bristol-city-west-bromwich-iddaa-oranlari-105777' (length=95)
  96 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/arbroath-ayr-united-iddaa-oranlari-105770' (length=88)
  97 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/queen-of-the-south-dundee-fc-iddaa-oranlari-105835' (length=97)
  98 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/partick-thistle-dunfermline-athletic-iddaa-oranlari-105831' (length=105)
  99 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/greenock-morton-alloa-athletic-iddaa-oranlari-105804' (length=99)
  100 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/dynamo-kiev-vorskla-iddaa-oranlari-105795' (length=88)
  101 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/crawley-town-stevenage-iddaa-oranlari-105790' (length=91)
  102 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/swindon-town-grimsby-town-iddaa-oranlari-105848' (length=94)
  103 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/salford-city-colchester-united-iddaa-oranlari-105838' (length=99)
  104 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/newport-county-bradford-city-iddaa-oranlari-105826' (length=97)
  105 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/crewe-alexandra-macclesfield-town-iddaa-oranlari-105791' (length=102)
  106 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/scunthorpe-united-forest-green-rovers-iddaa-oranlari-105839' (length=106)
  107 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/plymouth-argyle-cambridge-united-iddaa-oranlari-105833' (length=101)
  108 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/walsall-port-vale-iddaa-oranlari-105850' (length=86)
  109 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/leyton-orient-oldham-athletic-iddaa-oranlari-105821' (length=98)
  110 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/cheltenham-town-mansfield-town-iddaa-oranlari-105784' (length=99)
  111 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/carlisle-united-morecambe-iddaa-oranlari-105780' (length=94)
  112 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/northampton-town-exeter-city-iddaa-oranlari-105827' (length=97)
  113 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/woking-stockport-county-iddaa-oranlari-105856' (length=92)
  114 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/hartlepool-united-notts-county-iddaa-oranlari-105810' (length=99)
  115 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/dagenham-redbridge-solihull-moors-iddaa-oranlari-105793' (length=102)
  116 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/maidenhead-united-aldershot-town-iddaa-oranlari-105823' (length=101)
  117 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/bromley-wrexham-iddaa-oranlari-105778' (length=84)
  118 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/dover-athletic-afc-fylde-iddaa-oranlari-105796' (length=93)
  119 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/boreham-wood-yeovil-town-iddaa-oranlari-105774' (length=93)
  120 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/torquay-united-halifax-town-iddaa-oranlari-105849' (length=96)
  121 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/chorley-barnet-iddaa-oranlari-105787' (length=83)
  122 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/harrogate-town-eastleigh-iddaa-oranlari-105809' (length=93)
  123 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/chesterfield-ebbsfleet-united-iddaa-oranlari-105786' (length=98)
  124 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/kidderminster-harriers-york-city-iddaa-oranlari-105817' (length=101)
  125 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/spennymoor-town-alfreton-town-iddaa-oranlari-105842' (length=98)
  126 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/curzon-ashton-gloucester-city-iddaa-oranlari-105792' (length=98)
  127 => string 'https://www.iddaaorantahmin.com/iddaa-oranlari/altrincham-king-s-lynn-town-iddaa-oranlari-105768' (length=96)
  more elements...
```

Comment: the result is the same 5 links coming,There's more

Answer (score 0):

the result is the same 5 links coming,There's more why only 5 links are coming, I couldn't find a solution